# Fasten this Ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The following Ajax works , but it takes a while just to notify user on the client side that the username is already taken. Is there any ways to fasten this respons, or it's just normal behavior of Ajax.

Client :

```
    <title>Choose a username</title> 

    <style>
    #targetDiv {
      background-color: #FF9999;
      width: 40%;
    }
    </style>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
      var XMLHttpRequestObject = false; 

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      function getData(dataSource) 
      { 
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
          XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource); 

          XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
          { 
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
              XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
                if(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText == "taken"){
            var targetDiv = document.getElementById("targetDiv");

            targetDiv.innerHTML = "<div>That username is taken.</div>";
                }
            } 
          } 

          XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null); 
        }
      }

      function checkUsername(keyEvent) 
      {
        keyEvent = (keyEvent) ? keyEvent: window.event;
        input = (keyEvent.target) ? keyEvent.target : keyEvent.srcElement;

        if (keyEvent.type == "keyup") {
          var targetDiv = document.getElementById("targetDiv");
          targetDiv.innerHTML = "<div></div>";

          if (input.value) {
            getData("check.php?name=" +input.value);
          } 
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head> 

  <body>

    <H1>Choose a username</H1>

    Enter your new username <input id = "textField" type = "text" 
      name = "textField" onkeyup = "checkUsername(event)">

      <div id = "targetDiv"><div></div></div>

  </body> 

</html>
```

Server

```
<?php 
    if ($_GET["name"] == "steve"){
      echo "taken";
    }
    else {
      echo "ok";
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is "how to fasten the response".

The response is send by your server over the net.
The time taken for the net transfer will always vary.
But you can try to get faster responses of your server by optimizing the configuration of the webserver and PHP. You can test the response behavior of your server with a benchmark tool like `ab`or `siege`.
And then tweak, test, compare results, repeat-until-satisfied.
A request to the server is a request to the server. No matter, if it is done by a browser via ajax or the benchmark tool.

For instance, upgrading to PHP 5.6 and enabling and tuning the opcache, gives quite a performance boost, when compared to let's say PHP 5.3. There a lot of optimizations possible. The question is too broad to go into detail.

When looking at the client-side JS: this is plain-vanilla JS.
Not much room for improvements. The only thing which comes to my mind is
to change the xhrObject for IE from `"Microsoft.XMLHTTP`, which is really old, to `new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");` (and maybe add a fallback to `new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");`).

Comment: yes it is, I'm using php 5.3 , let me try to upgrade and see for the improvement. +1

Comment: Nice! Glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

It will always take some time to get the respond from the server, you can tune up your server to be faster but you will always have a delay.

However what you can do is show a loading splash while you are connecting with the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try storing usernames in Memcached as it will reduce the time taken for sql query.